# What is the instruction_data struct for program ED25519?

Tags: native-programs

I'm trying to deserialize the ED25519 program, but the struct I derived does not tally with the bytes in the instruction data (buffer)
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/master/sdk/src/ed25519_instruction.rs
Has anyone deserialized the ix data before? or is there any bytes I'm missing?

```
pub struct ED25519Data {
    padding: u8,
    signature_offset: u16,             // offset to ed25519 signature of 64 bytes
    signature_instruction_index: u16,  // instruction index to find signature
    public_key_offset: u16,            // offset to public key of 32 bytes
    public_key_instruction_index: u16, // instruction index to find public key
    message_data_offset: u16,          // offset to start of message data
    message_data_size: u16,            // size of message data
    message_instruction_index: u16,   // index of instruction data to get message data
    ix_data: ? 
}
```

ix_data isn't a fixed parameter, it varies.. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you are missing the first byte, In solana native programs the 1st byte represents enum of the request try doing from the second byte

Comment: @AbhishekFaliya i did ser! Still doesnt seem to tally

Comment: How exactly are you reading the data ? Are you reading from the account? or inspecting ix_data that you are sending ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of missing bits. If you follow along the code, you'll see how the instruction data vector is built up, creating this struct:

```
pub struct ED25519Data {
    num_signatures: u8,                // number of signatures to verify
    padding: u8,                       // padding to make the struct 2-aligned
    signature_offset: u16,             // offset to ed25519 signature of 64 bytes
    signature_instruction_index: u16,  // instruction index to find signature
    public_key_offset: u16,            // offset to public key of 32 bytes
    public_key_instruction_index: u16, // instruction index to find public key
    message_data_offset: u16,          // offset to start of message data
    message_data_size: u16,            // size of message data
    message_instruction_index: u16,   // index of instruction data to get message data
    signing_pubkey: Pubkey,           // signing pubkey, 32 bytes
    signature: Signature,             // signature for the message produced by the signing pubkey, 64 bytes
    message: [u8],                    // the bytes that were signed by signing_pubkey, could be any length (less than max transaction size)
}
```

Note that this isn't valid Rust because of the `message` field, which is just raw bytes that are signed.